# How to retain state of a fragment while switching between different fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity consisting of 3 fragments and a bottom navigation view which navigates the user to different fragments.
Let say the fragments are A, B and C.
The issue I am facing is that if I have performed some operation in A, and I navigate to B, then, when I again navigate to A (from bottom navigation view and NOT backpress) , the operations performed on A are lost, which I don't want.

For eg, in Youtube application, after searching something on Home fragment, if I navigate to "Subscriptions" or "Library", then if I renavigate to "Home", the search results are retained and also the state of the screen.
Kindly guide me how to achieve the same in my application

Comment: Can you include the code for how you perform the navigation between fragments? That will help identify the cause of your problem

Comment: When you're changing fragments going to created new instance... It's default behaviour using bottom nav otherwise you've to handle in the activity...

Comment: Declare fragments on top then init onCreate function. Like if(savInstanceState==null) then create fragment instance.  Later transaction place hide and show the fragments. You won't loss your state